# Using Inner Join in sqlite not returning the joined table's data

Tags: c#, sqlite, inner-join

I have some medicines that I want to get their localized names for, but am having trouble getting their localized names (they are blank in the return).

Here's the query (at runtime).

```
SELECT m.Id as Id, m.Name as Name, lm.Name as ProductName 
FROM Medicine m 
INNER JOIN LocalizedMedicine lm 
    ON lm.MeId = m.Id 
    AND lm.LanguageCode = 'en-US' 
ORDER BY m.Name
```

Here are my classes.

```
public class LocalizedMedicine
{        
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Indexed("LocMedName", 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public int MeId { get; set; }
}



public class Medicine : ObservableObject
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The universal Latin medical name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The primary Gene that this medicine uses.
    /// </summary>
    public int GeneId { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public Gene GeneUsed { get; set; }

    private string productName;
    /// <summary>
    /// The localized product name. It retrieves the
    /// localized name from AppResources if it is null.
    /// </summary>
    [Ignore]
    public string ProductName
    {
        get
        {
            // old attempt
            //if (productName == null)
            //    productName = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(Name);

            return productName;
        }
        set
        {
            productName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does a reference comparison and Name comparison, since the names (latin names)
    /// should be unique.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object m)
    {
        if (m == null) return false;
        if (m == this) return true;
        if (((Medicine)m).Name == this.Name) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is how I make the call (in a PCL)

```
public IEnumerable<Medicine> GetAllMedicines(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string langCode = cultureInfo.Name;

        // get all of the medicines and join LocalizedMedicine on MeId = med.Id
        // and LanguageCode = langCode


        var query = database.QueryAsync<Medicine>(
            "SELECT m.Id as Id, m.Name as Name, lm.Name as ProductName " +
            "FROM Medicine m " +
            "INNER JOIN LocalizedMedicine lm ON lm.MeId = m.Id AND lm.LanguageCode = " + "'" + langCode + "' " +
            "ORDER BY m.Name"
            );
        query.Wait();

        var result = query.Result;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `lm.LanguageCode = 'en-US'` be in a `WHERE` clause?  I'm not sure that it would make a difference but that would be more correct.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It would make a difference only for outer joins. Anyway, this is arguably more correct when the operation can be described as "join with the English translation".

Comment: The query looks OK. What is the exact value in the `langCode` variable? What are the values in the `LanguageCode` column? Does the query work if you execute it manually?

Comment: The current values in the language code column is 'en-US' (without the quotes). I'll do a bit more troubleshooting when I get home and will try changing ON to WHERE.

Comment: Well, I changed the query to WHERE, still didn't get any results. Ran the query in SQLite browser, got what I expected. I then looked at the Medicine class and saw that I had the ignore attribute on Product Name. smh. haha Thanks Guys! I didn't test the query with "on," so I don't know if that would work, but thanks a bunch to you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the query condition from "ON" to "WHERE" and removed the ignore attribute from the Medicine class. woops.